# Why have multiple classes in one source file?

Tags: objective-c

I was going over a sample Cocoa app from Apple (ImageKitDemo) and noticed that one of the source files (the .m file) actually contains the definition (interface and implementation) of another class. What are the benefits of doing this?

Comment: The advantage is that you can be lazier and not have to change between different code files all the time. But not encapsulating classes in their own files is a woefully bad design decision.

Comment: How you choose to reflect your classes in a file hierarchy is an organizational implementation detail. The most common approach is one class means one .h and one .m - but if it makes organizational sense, you can do whatever you want. Sometimes, for example, if it's simple model, I'll put interfaces for a specific model entity as well as an interface for a set/array of model objects into a single file, because it's very useful to have them next to each other (and they're tiny).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It also has the added benefit of emphasizing the fact that a certain class is *only* intended to serve as an implementation detail of another class, and should not be used elsewhere.

Comment: This makes sense for the same kind of classes which would be internal classes in java. I have seen classes grow to late because developers did not want to create another file pair, combining more than one class in the same file is a better solution off the classes are belt to a reasonably small size.

Answer (score 4):

Less total number of files in your project.  Besides that, no difference.  You could write an entire project in 1 .m file if you really wanted to.

Comment: Who doesn't like scrolling down 100000 lines of code in a single file? ;)